# How do i correctly reference Vue.js node_module from electron-forge boilerplate?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, electron, electron-forge

This is a rookie question.  I'm trying to take some baby-steps into Electron, Vue, Webpack, and Node.  To that end, I've used electron-forge to spool out a boilerplate project as a starting point, like this:

> npx create-electron-app my-project --template=typescript-webpack

After the project has been created everything (seemingly) works as expected.  If I make any edits I can see webpack is invoked and reloading the content reveals my edits.  So far so good.

My next step was to introduce the simplest Vue.js 'hello world' content I could.  First, I install Vue.js using NPM, like this:

> npm install "vue"

I then edit the boilerplate index.html to look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <script src="../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Hello World!</h1>
    <p>Welcome to your Electron application.</p>
    <div id="vue-app">
      {{ message }}
    </div>
    <script>
      var app = new Vue({
        el: '#vue-app',
        data: {
        message: 'This message is from Vue!'
        }
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which does not work.  If I change the script tag to use the CDN for the Vue.js script (instead of the node_modules folder), everything works as expected.

My conclusion is that although I can reference Vue.js in my node_modules folder at *design time* that location does not exist in my output at *run time*.  I'm not certain if that is due to how webpack is configured, or due to how electron works - but it strongly implies there must be something I need to do, either programmatically or via the webpack configuration to properly reference the script.

So what is the right way to 'reference' the local Vue.js script?

Thanks!

Comment: Revisiting this question much later and I've marked n-smits answer as correct.  If you use the vue cli to create your app, and then add electron-builder the process just works out-of-the-box.  i was hung up on approaching this brass-backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference vue via some bundler like webpack (otherwise, like you said, it is not available at runtime). Your method won't work because the generated file structure isn't the same as the one you have during 'design time'

Here's an example with vue-cli which sets up a starter project:

```sh
npm i -g @vue/cli
vue create project-name
cd project-name
vue add electron-builder
npm install
```

Done. Your project is operational.

---

With one little caveat you would encounter later, if you are using vue-router. Add the following in `router.js` (it changes router mode to hash instead of history so it works with electron).

```js
export default new Router({
    mode: process.env.IS_ELECTRON ? 'hash' : 'history',
})
```

---

As a sidenote, vue-cli abstracts away *a lot* of config. If you ever get lost, just print it out with

```sh
vue inspect > ./app/inspect.js.md
```

(The part after > means save to the named file, otherwise it would print it out in your console.) Check it out, that's the correct set up you're looking for, just auto created with vue-cli.

Also, check out the generated `/public/index.html`, it has no mention of importing vue ;)

Best of luck

Comment: I appreciate the response - after spending some time fooling around with this it isn't really even a Vue thing.  For example, I could install _anything_ with NPM and try to reference it using a <script> tag with no luck.  So either electron-forge useless out of the box (which I doubt) or there is some obvious secret sauce I am missing.

Comment: As for "you can install anything with npm" well... You can't install a car :P -- But either way, before I lose you with stupid jokes, the point is you're already installing from npm with `npx create-electron-app my-project --template=typescript-webpack`, just a different package. The reason I suggest electron-builder is because it worked for me, while -forge didn't. If it work for you, great, but either way, it is coming from npm... As for installing vue-cli, that's just a helper, a dev dependency that's not even visible in the final app. Either way, I suggest you check it out. Cheers

Comment: You can reference with script tag only if you mark it as a module, but what you found in the end is the usual way anyway :) -- to import it in js, not via dom via script tag. One note to your answer, you don't need to `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';`, you can simply `import Vue from 'vue'` The difference? Besides fewer characters, I'm not sure, but you could be missing expanded debugging since you're using the dist specifically.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info; just to note: If anyone else is plowing this same field, I initially tried the import as just 'vue' and it did not work.  I don't fully understand why, but googling the issue I discovered I was not alone; and instead it was suggested using the longer 'vue/dist/vue.js' which worked without problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering, I came up with this solution:

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Hello World!</h1>
    <p>Welcome to your Electron application.</p>
    <div id="vue-app">{{ message }}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I then added an import statement to the electron-forge boilerplate *renderer.ts*, like this:

```
import './vueapp.js';
```

and finally, I created a new script file called *vueapp.js* like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
});
```

I welcome feedback and comments; this may or may not be the correct approach and would love to hear how others have done this.